# Кодировка текста php-скрипта в консоли в Windows

Tags: php, windows, cmd, кодировка, консоль

У меня есть большое PHP-приложение, запускающееся через консоль. Все файлы с кодировкой UTF-8, вместо `echo` использую свою функцию для вывода текста.
Консоль Windows (до 10-ой) никак не хочет выводить русские символы из PHP-скрипта. Для теста делал так: `echo mb_convert_encoding("'йоу привет'", "CP866", "UTF-8");` - первые две буквы выводит, остальные буквы - невидимые символы.
Пробовал кодировку в консоли поменять на Windows-1251: `chcp 1251`. При этом ***ЛЮБЫЕ*** русские буквы в консоли превратились в кракозябры. Затем `echo mb_convert_encoding("'йоу привет'", "CP1251", "UTF-8");` - все буквы невидимые
Пробовал перевести кодировку консоли в UTF-8: `chcp 65001`. Язык в консоли изменился на английский и теперь вообще отказывается хоть как-то принимать русские буквы. Затем `echo "'йоу привет'";` и просто кракозябры. В Windows 10 никаких проблем с кодировкой нет, даже ничего переводить не надо. В версиях Windows ниже - ни в какую.

Comment: Смотрите кодировку самого файла php. Она должна совпадать с той, что прописана в консоли windows

Answer (score 0):

Там дело не в кодировке видимо, а в шрифте. Стандартный Consolas не поддерживает кириллицу (в Windows 10 это уже пофиксили).
Так что поменяйте его в свойствах консоли на шрифт Lucida Console:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]